# Mejor práctica sobre manejo de repos CodeCommit en multiples cuentas AWS

Tags: nodejs, git, aws, buenas-prácticas, deployment

Tengo una aplicación Node.js que implemento como Lambdas a través del framework Serverless

Tenemos a la vez, 2 cuentas de AWS distintas (para Testing y Producción). Estas cuentas no tienen el peering habilitado (por cuestiones de seguridad, invisibilidad total entre ambientes de Test y Prod)

Subí mi código a codecommit, pero por esta separación de cuentas, lo tengo "duplicado"... la misma app en un repo distinto en cada una de las cuentas. Esto me impide mantener un único repositorio para mi aplicación, y en parte me obliga a tener que hacer movimientos manuales de objetos...

Existe alguna buena práctica que permita manejar un solo repositorio, de una aplicación que se debe implementar en 2 cuentas distintas no conectadas?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

> Tenemos a la vez, 2 cuentas de AWS distintas

Ya empezamos mal. Las cuentas no están pensadas para *usos* sino para **personas**, es decir, cada persona debería tener una única cuenta de AWS ... todas ligadas al espacio de trabajo común. Esto te permite, por ejemplo limitar el acceso a alguien que por cualquier razón se va de la empresa o que simplemente cambia de rol.

> Subí mi código a codecommit, pero por esta separación de cuentas, lo tengo "duplicado"

La única explicación para que esto pase es que esos usuarios no se han creado a partir de una misma **cuenta root**. Me explico:

Cuando creas una cuenta en AWS el sistema te proporciona un usuario root. Este usuario debería ser utilizado únicamente para la configuración básica de la cuenta... que son dos pasos tontos, siendo uno de ellos crear un usuario para administrar el sistema (tras realizar estos pasos lo recomendable es eliminar esta cuenta root... por seguridad). Este administrador puede crear, posteriormente, todas las cuentas de usuario que crea pertinentes... y todas ellas tendrán (si los roles asignados a las mismas lo permiten) acceso a los mismos recursos de AWS.

Gestionar correctamente el sistema de IAMs y Roles permite compartimentar el espacio de trabajo común para diferentes fines, de tal forma que el espacio de trabajo destinado a desarrollo no se solape con el de producción... pero todos estos espacios de trabajo están asociados a la misma cuenta de AWS.

Es decir, que una misma cuenta de AWS podría tener el repositorio que comentas y aparte los espacios de trabajo de testing y de producción, de tal forma que solo algunos usuarios pueden acceder a testing, otros solo a producción, otros a ambos entornos y, lo más importante, **ambos entornos** comparten repositorio.

Además, tener todo centralizado en una misma cuenta de AWS permite centralizar todo el tema de pagos, lo cual seguro que el encargado de este menester lo agradece.